# Change color of specific text while generating Excel header

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am generating an Excel in my spring based application using apache-poi. While populating the Header for excel i want the specific word of the given sentence in different color.
E.g- suppose i want my header with value `Address (*"MANDATORY)` with below given color.
`Address` - in Black Color
`*"MANDATORY` - in Red Color
I came through a method for changing the fontColor provided by apache-poi but that is changing the font color of whole cell value but i want a specific text in different color.
How to resolve above issue ?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/apache-poi-cell-multiple-styles)

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your requirement the cell would must contain rich text string content. This is possible using `Cell.setCellValue(RichTextString value)`. The [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) can be created as it is described in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#RichText).

Let's have an example which provides a method `createRichTextString(Workbook workbook, String[] textParts, Font[] fonts)` which creates a `RichTextString` for an array of text parts using an array of fonts.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelRichText {

 static RichTextString createRichTextString(Workbook workbook, String[] textParts, Font[] fonts) {
  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(String.join("", textParts));
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  for (int tp = 0; tp < textParts.length; tp ++) {
   Font font = null;
   if (tp < fonts.length) font = fonts[tp];
   end += textParts[tp].length();
   if (font != null) richTextString.applyFont(start, end, font);
   start += textParts[tp].length();
  }
  return richTextString;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  String fileName = (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook)?"Excel.xlsx":"Excel.xls";

  Font font = workbook.createFont(); // default font

  Font fontRed = workbook.createFont();
  fontRed.setColor(Font.COLOR_RED);

  String[] textParts = new String[]{"Address (", "*\"MANDATORY", ")"};
  Font[] fonts = new Font[]{font, fontRed, font};

  RichTextString richTextString = createRichTextString(workbook, textParts, fonts);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(richTextString);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```